# How to change the following code in VB.net in order to use it in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How to change the following code in VB.net in order to use it in asp.net using VB , I got  the following  errors:

1. row is not member  of GridView
2. Me.Qty.Index in not member of GridView

   ```
   For Each rows As DataGridViewRow In Me.InvoiceDetailsDataGridView.row
       If Row.Cells(Me.Qty.Index).Value = "" Then Exit For

       strSQL = "INSERT INTO InvoiceDetails (InvoiceID, Qty, ProductName, Price) VALUES(" & identity & ", " & Row.Cells(Me.Qty.Index).Value & ",'" & Row.Cells(Me.ProductName.Index).Value & "'," & Row.Cells(Me.Price.Index).Value & ")"

       cmd = New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
   Next Row
   ```

Thank you